# Drawing a arrow circle between two overlapping triangles

Tags: tikz-arrows

I want to draw a cycle involving these two curved triangles but I am failing.

[image]

This is what I have so far:

[image]

```
\begin{document}

\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=gray!20] (0.5,3) node[]{} -- (4.5,5) node[]{} -- (8.5,3) node[]{} -- cycle;
\draw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=gray!20] (0,1) node[]{} -- (2,3) node[]{} -- (4,1) node[]{} -- cycle;
\circlearrowright

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings,
                positioning
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
->-/.style={decoration={markings,% switch on markings
                        mark=between positions 0 and 0.7 step 0.6
                        with {\arrow[thick]{Straight Barb}}
                        },
            postaction={decorate}
            }
                        ]
\draw[fill=gray!10] (0,0.0) -- ++ (5, 0) -- ++ (-3,3) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!20, semitransparent] 
                    (1,0.2) coordinate (A) node[]{} 
                            -- ++ (1,-1) -- ++ (-2,0) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed, red, rotate=15, ->-]     (A) circle[x radius=7mm, y radius=4mm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Instead of use the `semitransparent` option for the second triangle may be better to use `fill opacity=0,5`. Using it image is:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 230; green, 230; blue, 230 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (250,102) -- (395,238) -- (105,238) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Triangle [id:dp9078985226024554] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 230; green, 230; blue, 230 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (173.5,214) -- (228,275) -- (119,275) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp8846225739607101] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][dash pattern={on 4.5pt off 4.5pt}] (144.59,235.22) .. controls (139.33,221.03) and (149.76,204.08) .. (167.88,197.36) .. controls (186.01,190.64) and (204.96,196.7) .. (210.22,210.88) .. controls (215.48,225.07) and (205.05,242.02) .. (186.93,248.74) .. controls (168.81,255.46) and (149.85,249.4) .. (144.59,235.22) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (205.06,217.71) .. controls (206.85,211.75) and (207.04,206.89) .. (205.63,203.13) .. controls (208.64,205.79) and (213.25,207.35) .. (219.45,207.81) ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ] (151.1,218.32) .. controls (146.62,222.65) and (144.08,226.8) .. (143.48,230.77) .. controls (142.15,226.98) and (138.89,223.36) .. (133.71,219.93) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```